# How to add every Sunday in sequential order with 3 blank cells under each date?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates, date

How to add every Sunday in sequential order with 3 blank cells under each date?

For example:

```
March 22
Blank cell
Blank cell
Blank cell
March 29
etc etc
```

Comment: @Cornelius Please don't add meta-tags to questions.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution with a Formula :

```
    A1 : =ArrayFormula(if(
                          mod(ROW(A1:A100),4)=1,
                          text((round(ROW(A1:A100)/4)*7)+43730,"dddd dd mmm yy")
                         ,)
                     )
```

---

#### Solution with drag and drop

1. Enter the dates in the cells : `A1` is the first sunday,
   `A5` is the second with this formula `=A1+7`
   `A9` is the third : `=A5+7`
2. Highlight the cells `A5:A12`. You’ll see a small blue box in the lower right corner.
3. Drag the blue box any number of cells down or across.

---

#### Result :

Formula
[image: solution with forumula]
Drag
[image: before]
[image: after]